# Laravel 4 lazy loading with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel, eloquent

How to do lazy loading at Laravel 4 with angularjs?

For example, I want some data about posts.
So, using Laravel RESTful API of post, I can get data by a $http get request from angular and echo it out like this.

On L4 blade / Angular

```
{{ post.title }}
```

Now, I want to access a data which is on other table (let users) and has a one to one relation with posts table. Let it is the post author info. So,

On L4 blade:

```
{{ post.author.name }}
```

but angular can not do that.

I know, we can eager load the author info like:

```
Post::with('author')->get();
```

but, it want just like L4, when we need it, it will fetch, otherwise not.

Comment: Just an after thought, not specifically related to your question, but have you considered only using Laravel for your API and have your UI purely in AngularJS? I am working on a project and that is what I am doing. 

So basically your Laravel's API only reads/writes to the DB (and minimal logic), and your AngularJS does the rendering.

Comment: I wanted that exactly. Use L4 just for API purpose, and angular as frontend.

Comment: Well, I am doing that exactly. I created a folder in /public called /api and moved the `index.php` to it (so my calls to Laravel will be `/api/my-resource`, and the /public folder is the `index.html` and my `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `protected $appends = ['author'];` on your `Post` model to always load these relationships when the results are cast to JSON (which is what happens when you send them to angular.

Comment: But there may have many relations with post, so all the relations will be fetched because when I will request $http get to post, I might need author data or might not. But it will be always fetched. Same for other relations with Post model. I think it won't be a good practise. I wanted something like when I need author data it will fetch that, but not always. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the dilemma. In my experience, it's best to load all of the relationships into the scope, and use what you need. This way, you won't have to make extra ajax calls for the same information. You could add prototype methods that do this for you, but seems like more work than its worth IMHO.

Comment: So far, your suggested approach is the best approach. Thanks.